# Mysql can't select the record in the table

Tags: mysql, select

I have a mysql table with a null-able int column named 'status', and I have two records in the table where one of the status is 2 when the other is NULL, but when I select the records with query 'status!=2', the record (status=null) is not shown.

```
mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> desc admin_user;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| acct_name   | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_name   | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status      | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| role        | int(11)          | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| create_date | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| update_date | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, acct_name, status from admin_user;
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | acct_name | status |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | letme     |   NULL |
|  3 | admin     |      2 |
+----+-----------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, acct_name, status from admin_user where status=2;
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | acct_name | status |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  3 | admin     |      2 |
+----+-----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, acct_name, status from admin_user where status IS NULL;
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | acct_name | status |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | letme     |   NULL |
+----+-----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, acct_name, status from admin_user where status!=2;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As you can see, the record whose status is NULL can not be selected using the query 'status!=2'. I also tried 'status<>2'. Can anybody help?

Comment: Try `COALESCE(status, 0) !=2` ;).

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nulls are really [interesting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html).

> The NULL value can be surprising until you get used to it.
>   Conceptually, NULL means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated
>   somewhat differently from other values.

What's more

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to
>   test for NULL

There are lots of different ways to write this. One of them being:

```
select id, acct_name, status from admin_user where status IS NULL
  OR status != 2
```

Alterantively as @shA.t suggested.

```
select id, acct_name, status from table1 where COALESCE(status, 0)  != 2
```

Just check that 0 is indeed a number that doesn't appear any where else in the table.

Comment: NULL is like the NaN of the SQL world. It can be pretty strange if you don't know how it works.

Comment: Thanks you all, Null is really strange in SQL world!