# How can I exclude NULL of not equal operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, operators, where-clause

In this part of query:

```
. . . WHERE col <> 10
```

It matches everything except `10` and `NULL`. While I want to match everything except only `10`. So how can I exclude `NULL` of that?

Comment: where col not in(10) should work

Comment: where col is null or col <> 10;

Comment: @Satya No, it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql can't select the record in the table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974750/mysql-cant-select-the-record-in-the-table)

Comment: @Priyanshu Yes it works. But isn't there any better solution? Something like `<=>` which is safe against `null`. Actually your question is fine but it is  containing two separated conditions. I like to do that by 1 condition.

Comment: @stack it should as per the theory. Can you check for the value correctness in col

Comment: hi again @stack, hope this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974750/mysql-cant-select-the-record-in-the-table/36974829#36974829

Comment: @e4c5 Yes .. it worked perfectly..! +1 for your answer in that question.

Comment: @stack thanks and glad to have been of help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This you can use for MySQL,

```
...WHERE IFNULL(col,0) <> 10
```

If the value of col is `NULL` then `IFNULL(col,0)` will convert the value to `'0'` and perform the comparison. So you will get all the records except only `10`.

Comment: That's good .. thank you .. upvote .. Just what's the different `IFNULL()` and `COALESCE()` in this case?

Comment: Plz refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528468/what-is-the-difference-bewteen-ifnull-and-coalesce-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the condition `col != 10` (in MySQL) means "row where `col` has a value that is not 10". `NULL` is not a value so `NULL` rows aren't matched. If they were, you could have problems with `NULL`s cascading into other parts of your logic messing things up, since they don't use the same equality logic as values.

As far as I understand, doing it in two conditions (`col IS NULL OR col != 10`) is the proper way since by MySQL logic you're asking for two separate things. "rows where `col` has a value that is not 10, or rows where `col` has no value".

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
....col <> 10 OR col IS NULL

for null values